# fill between more than two curves matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to fill between 3 lines in the following problem. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Construct lines
# x > 0
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 2000)
# C1
y1 = (36-2*x)/6
# C2
y2 = (30-5*x)/3
# C3
y3 = (40-8*x)/2
# C4
# y4 = 0*x

# Make plot
plt.plot(x, y1, label=r'$2 x_{1} + 6 x_{2}\leq 36$')
plt.plot(x, y2, label=r'$x_{1} + 3 x_{2}\leq 30$')
plt.plot(x, y3, label=r'$x_{1} + 2 x_{2}\leq 40$')
# plt.plot(x, y4, label=r'$x_{1}, x_{2}\geq 0$')
plt.xlim((0, 16))
plt.ylim((0, 11))
plt.xlabel(r'$x_1$')
plt.ylabel(r'$x_2$')

# Fill feasible region
y5 = np.minimum(0, 0)
y6 = np.maximum(y2, y3)
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='grey', alpha=0.5,
                interpolate=True)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

I'd like to fill what is hatched in red in  the image  below (between y1, y2, y3, and zero)[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894225/using-fill-between-and-min-max-to-represent-inequalities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could fill between zero and the minimum of the three curves:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 2000)
y1 = (36 - 2 * x) / 6
y2 = (30 - 5 * x) / 3
y3 = (40 - 8 * x) / 2

plt.plot(x, y1, label=r'$2 x_{1} + 6 x_{2}\leq 36$')
plt.plot(x, y2, label=r'$x_{1} + 3 x_{2}\leq 30$')
plt.plot(x, y3, label=r'$x_{1} + 2 x_{2}\leq 40$')
plt.xlim((0, 16))
plt.ylim((0, 11))
plt.xlabel(r'$x_1$')
plt.ylabel(r'$x_2$')

plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='grey', alpha=0.5,
                 interpolate=True)
plt.fill_between(x, 0, np.min([y1, y2, y3], axis=0), color='red', alpha=0.5, hatch='//',
                 interpolate=True, label='$intersection$')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

1. `np.vstack([y1, y2, y3])` creates a 3-row array from your 3 "y" arrays.
2. `….min(0)` computes minimum along each column, so it is actually
   a minimum of your 3 source arrays (also with negative values for higher *x*).
3. `….clip(min=0)` transforms the above negative elements to *0*.

So add to your code:

```
plt.fill_between(x, 0, np.vstack([y1, y2, y3]).min(0).clip(min=0),
    color='yellow', alpha=0.5, interpolate=True)
```

e.g. after your first *fill_between*.

For your data, and code with the above instruction added, I got:

[image]

If you want, change the filling color to whatever suits your needs.